# Blue line on a dialog

Tags: android, dialog

[image]

When I create a class that extends from Dialog, I have the blue line at the top of the dialog as you can see in the picture (I didn't do anything to have it. The simple fact to extend from dialog create this blue line). 
Do you have an idea why?

Answer (score 1):

most probably this is happens based on version of Android OS you have on your testing device! Did you try to test it on different OS?

Comment: Yes it depends on the version